# Index-wise Mode of 2D arrays

Tags: arrays, matlab, matrix

I am wondering how to arrange the input parameters of the mode function in order to calculate the matrix of modes for input 2D matrices in just one line of code..

for example

```
x=[7 2;5 10]
y=[7 1;8 3 ]
z=[7 2;8 10]
```

I want mode(x,y,z) gives this output

```
output=[7 2;8 10]  // these are the most occurring elements in each index
```

I have done it this way, but it takes around 2 sec with high dimensional matrices, so I am looking for more efficient way to solve it.

```
for i=1:2
   for j=1:2
      votes=[];
      for k=1:length(arrs)  // arrs is a cell array of matrices
          votes=[votes arrs{1,k}(i,j)]; 
      end
       res(i,j) = mode(votes);
   end
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a 3 dimensional array composed of `x,y,z`, then call `mode` along the third dimension to get the desired result.

```
xyz = cat(3,x,y,z);
ans = mode(xyz,3);

ans =

     7     2
     8    10
```

Comment: on 4 arrays each of size 16k elements, ur solution is better than mine. It takes 0.48 seconds. I will vote +1 for ur answer and wait for an even better solution. If there is no more efficient "faster" solution provided by anyone else, I will choose your answer.

Answer (score 1):

This might be slightly faster than [Falimond's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32793657/2586922) because it uses two dimensions instead of three:

```
output = reshape(mode([x(:).'; y(:).'; z(:).'], 1), size(x));
```

It works by creating a matrix where each row contains the values from of the original matrices (`[x(:).'; y(:).'; z(:).']`), finding the mode of each column (`mode(..., 1)`), and reshaping the result into a matrix (`reshape(..., size(x))`).

Do try with your matrix sizes and Matlab version to find out which is fastest.

Comment: Thanks Luis for ur answer, without the reshaping operation, ur solution is as fast as Falimond one.